# Jackson 1.9 @JsonTypeInfo visible discriminator property

Tags: json, jackson

Jackson 2.x has the "visible" property to be able to use the discriminator property in your bean:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "discriminator", visible=true)
```

Is there an equivalent for Jackson 1.9?